# Permission denied when importing paramiko from flask app -apache wsgi mod

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, paramiko

I've been trying to deploy my flask app using apache as a server(wsgi_mod). I created all the necessary files (.wsgi and .conf file for apache).

But when i request the page i get a 500 error. Checking the logs shows a

```
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.746453 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450] mod_wsgi (pid=74305): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.746912 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450] mod_wsgi (pid=74305): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.wsgi'.
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.750486 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.750808 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/var/www/html/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.750995 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     from my_flask_app import app as application
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.751224 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/var/www/html/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.py", line 2, in <module>
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.751411 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     import paramiko
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.751600 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.751819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.752023 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 32, in <module>
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.752224 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.752446 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.752625 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     import pkg_resources
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.752834 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.753009 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     @_call_aside
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.753215 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.753405 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     f(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.753597 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.753806 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.754000 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 646, in _build_master
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.754175 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     ws = cls()
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.754390 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 639, in __init__
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.754590 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     self.add_entry(entry)
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.754782 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 695, in add_entry
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.754981 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.755178 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2012, in find_on_path
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.755382 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450]     if len(os.listdir(fullpath)) == 0:
[Fri Jul 05 12:39:18.755643 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 74305] [remote 10.1.1.50:41450] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Werkzeug-0.15.4.dist-info'
```

I'm trying to deploy this application in a debian 9 server. I've tested it on my kali box and it worked fine just by installing flask and paramiko and configuring apache.

I've tried rinstalling some packages like paramiko, flask and Werkzeug but with no success.

I even created a new app with a simple hello world message. It works fine until i import paramiko and then i get the "permission denined" error.

My test app contains three files.

- my_flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import paramiko
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

- my_flask_app.wsgi

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/')
from my_flask_app import app as application
application.secret_key = 'thisisasecretkey'
```

- my_flask_app.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     # Add machine's IP address (use ifconfig command)
     ServerName 10.1.1.50
     # Give an alias to to start your website url with
     WSGIScriptAlias /testFlask /var/www/html/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.wsgi
     WSGIDaemonProcess my_flask_app user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
     WSGIProcessGroup my_flask_app
     #WSGIScriptAlias /testFlask /var/www/html/benchmarkerPHP/benchmarkerPHP.wsgi
     #<Directory /var/www/html/benchmarkerPHP/>
     <Directory /var/www/html/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/>
                # set permissions as per apache2.conf file
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     LogLevel warn
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The apache user didn't have the needed permission to read from that directory. We only to add the read permission for the other group with the following command :

```
chmod o+r /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/*
```